# Android MediaRecorder error handling, mic problems checks?

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I am doing an Audio recording application. I have have managed to do recording using [MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) API.

But some checks/monitoring I am not able to do :

```
Case 1 : How do I detect if the mic is in use already by another application,
Case 2 : How do I detect if mic on phone is erroneous,
Case 3 : Something went wrong during recording going on,
```

For case 2 above,

I have implemented an error listener as follows :

```
mRecorder.setOnErrorListener(new MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onError(MediaRecorder mr, int errCode, int extra) {
                if (errCode == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_ERROR_UNKNOWN ||
                        errCode == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED) {

                }
            }
        });
```

I am relying on the  `MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_ERROR_UNKNOWN` constant that something is wrong here. I am expecting some of the case 3 errors will also may recieve in this handler.

Isn't there any way I can query the information about phones mic ? Which will give me some specific error or info codes like, `MIC_IS_ERRONEOUS, HEAD_PHONE_MIC_IN_USE, PHONES_MIC_IN_USE, HEADPHONE_NOT_PROPERLY_INSERTED, MIC_IS_IN_USE_ALREADY`  etc.

Are there any API available on Android framework to perform these checks ?